# Jackson: marshal to JSON with UpperCamelCase

Tags: java, json, jackson, apache-camel

I have a POJO object that has UpperCamelCase naming. When I do the call to Jackson's ObjectMapper to serialize/marshal it to JSON, the result is lowerCamelCase for field names.

The call is now trivial:

### Heading

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
jsonText = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(myObjectToJson);
```

how I can tell ObjectMapper to make UpperCamelCase? Or is it some sort of set-in-stone JSON standard?

I use jackson inside Apache Camel.

Comment: UPD: solved it by exposing fields to public  and adding @JsonIgnore to getters. It turns out that getters are serialized as lowercamelcase, but fields serialized literally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

edited original answer.

Jackson uses camelCasing as default it seems. They have implemented a PascalCasing strategy. Try this:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.setPropertyNamingStrategy(PropertyNamingStrategy.PASCAL_CASE_TO_CAMEL_CASE);
```

Or annotate your fields with `@JsonProperty("UpperCaseProperty")`